# jQuery - use .each to apply .droppable to several classes

Tags: jquery, loops, draggable, each, droppable

I have several classes that need all need the same information in .droppable() added to them. The only difference is one of the attributes. Is there a way I could have this with an .each loop instead of typing them all out? Example:

```
$(".te").droppable({
drop: swapPlayer,
hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
accept: '.te'
});

$(".rb").droppable({
drop: swapPlayer,
hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
accept: '.rb'
});
```

And so on with a bunch of other classes.  I tried doing something like this but couldn't get it to work. I feel like I'm close though.

```
var pos = {".qb", ".rb"};
jQuery.each( pos, function( i, val ) {
  $(val).droppable({
    drop: swapPlayer,
    hoverClass: 'drop-hover',
    accept: val
  });
});
```

Comment: `var pos = [".qb", ".rb"];`  ???

Comment: sorry, but this is the answer to your issue. Use an array: `var pos = [".qb", ".rb"];` instead of an invalid object...

Comment: Sorry for the first comment, I didn't realize you changed the {} to [] at first and had no idea what you meant. Thank you!

Comment: np, my bad, should have explained it... And `???` was a shortcut for: "could you test it?!" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here we go, use an array, not an invalid object:

```
var pos = [".qb", ".rb"];
```